# Natural frequency mass-spring system on inclined plane

Tags: homework-and-exercises, newtonian-mechanics, frequency, spring, oscillators

[image]

I have to find $\omega$ for this system using the forces. I have a disc $radius = R, mass = M$

By using $F=ma$, I get $mg\sin\theta - kx =  m\ddot{x}$

then
$$-g\sin\theta + \frac{kx}{m} + \ddot{x} = 0$$

$\omega = \sqrt{\frac{k}{m}}$

But the correct answer is  $\omega = \sqrt{\frac{2k}{3m}}$

I don't see where my errors are.

Comment: You are supposed to assume that the disc rolls.

Comment: So I have the torque $T = I\ddot\theta$, but I don't see how to plug the force.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There's rolling going on here.

Assuming no slipping, you have $\tau = R mg\sin\theta\implies I\alpha = fR$ where $f$ is friction. Since $a=\alpha R$ then you have $$C mR^2 \dfrac \alpha R = fR\implies Cma=f$$
where $I=CmR^2$.

Then by Newton's second Law, $$ma=mg\sin\theta-kx-f\implies ma=mg\sin\theta-kx-Cma$$

Then use the chain rule $a=\dfrac {dv}{dt}=\dfrac{dv}{dx}\dfrac{dx}{dt}=\dfrac{dv}{dx}v$, get the equation of motion for $x(t)$ and identify your $\omega$.